# How to consume HTTPS webservice having wsdl and soap12 version.

Tags: ios, objective-c, wsdl, soap1.2

While sending soap1.2 request what are the namespaces we need to use in soapbody? Any sample code available in ios programming?

Answer (score 0):

SOAP request namespace start with following prefix.

http://www.w3.org/2003/05/

And depending on the type of element there are suffix. so for eg.

- Envelope - http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope
- Addressing Header - http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing

Check [This](https://techmegabyte.wordpress.com/2014/12/18/soap-web-service-implementation-in-ios/) example.